# UIDataView selection not posted back

Tags: iphone

I am a new to iPhone programming and struggling hard to get answer to a basic issue. I have created a single row UITableview on a UIView and want cell click to redirect to another UITableView screen to select one of the available values. All goes fine, till the select on select view, but after clicking back button the new selected value is not reflected. I am using this code

On my Calling View

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // open a alert with an OK and cancel button
    UIViewController *nextViewController = nil;
    nextViewController = [[CategorySelectionView alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
    ((CategorySelectionView *)nextViewController).category = parentCategory;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:nextViewController animated:YES];
    [nextViewController release];//break;

}

On selection View

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    // If there was a previous selection, unset the accessory view for its cell.
    NSManagedObject *currentCategory = category;

    if (currentCategory != nil) {
        NSInteger index = [categoryTypes indexOfObject:currentCategory];
        NSIndexPath *selectionIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:index inSection:0];
        UITableViewCell *checkedCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:selectionIndexPath];
        checkedCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    }

    // Set the checkmark accessory for the selected row.
    [[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark];    

    category = [categoryTypes objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

}
```

This is an extract form Apple developer Recipe code but is not working for me. Any help would really be appreciated. Also if I could be redirected to examples of using tableView screen as selector, would be equally helpful. Look forward to your help

Comment: what you mean the state not reflected ?

Comment: @Jhaliya : I am sorry if I was not clear - I am calling View2 from a UICell on View1 for user to select a value. So on view2, when I select the value and click back button, the selected value is not updated on view1

Comment: Are you adding the new selected value in view1 ? and Is view1 subview of UICell ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to deselect the cell use below in your `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`

```
[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];
```

So your code must be like below.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    // If there was a previous selection, unset the accessory view for its cell.
    NSManagedObject *currentCategory = category;

    if (currentCategory != nil) {
        NSInteger index = [categoryTypes indexOfObject:currentCategory];
        NSIndexPath *selectionIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:index inSection:0];
        UITableViewCell *checkedCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:selectionIndexPath];
        checkedCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    }

    // Set the checkmark accessory for the selected row.
    [[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark];    
    category = [categoryTypes objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    //Add it to deselect the selected cell
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];    
}
```

**EDITED:**

When you click on the back button, get the event for that and update the data (which is displaying by your tableview) then call `reloadData` method on your `UITableView` instance.
To get updated value, you could use the reloadData method of `UITableView`.

Use it as below

```
[tableView reloadData];
```

Comment: Thanks Jhaliya, Yes it was there and got commented in debugging. Bringing it back does not help either :(